# Request Information - Android Mobile Device Sharing Function

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, shared-libraries

Whenever a person shares content on his phone, where is that data stored? What I mean by data here is record of a content being shared on that device from it's destination to it's reception. Where is that data stored? Can that data be used and integrated into an app? Can an app/program be built around that data?

Comment: What does "shares content on his phone" mean?

Comment: If I am sending/saving a file from my whatsapp to another app on my phone. that's what I mean, apologize if I was unclear with my question, I am not a developer, I wanted to simply post a question but StackExchange made me create an account.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever a person shares content on his phone, where is that data stored?

That is determined by the developers of the sending app (WhatsApp, in your scenario from your comment).

> Can that data be used and integrated into an app?

Generally speaking, only if the sending app (WhatsApp) shares it with that app.